# Can I recharge a cell phone battery using USB?

Tags: usb, cells

Is it possible to recharge a cell phone's battery even if USB is disabled or blocked on the system?

Comment: USB is disabled on the computer?

Comment: use a wallwart.

Comment: @soandos , not sure of Disable or blocked it's basically a client PC where no data transfer supposed to happen.

Comment: Yeah its most probably disabled, it won't work.

Comment: @Sujoy, if the answer answers your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer. Welcome to SuperUser.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Blocked** and **disabled** are not the same thing to my understanding. *Blocked* means the USB port I/O is restricted but the port still has power, in which case it will able to charge your phone. *Disabled* means the USB port has no power whatsover, in which case it cannot charge anything.

Answer (score 1):

How are the mice and keyboard connected?  Via a PS2 port?  You could take a PS2 to USB adapter and charge your phone that way.  If you dont have one, most IT geeks have them lying around.  I just checked and I have 10 sitting in a box.  :P

Comment: Nice one. could be another way to charge phone.  
Sorry could not vote up; don't have required reputation , will do once I get that. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the USB port on computer is disabled, then it will not charge.

Comment: I was surprised by this answer, but I looked it up.  You are right.

Comment: The reason is basically because it is not getting any power though the mobo. This means no data, and no power to charge anything.

Comment: I would have thought they would still be powered, just not passing date.  You learn something new every day.

Comment: If I want something disabled, why would I want to keep it powered?

Comment: the confusion is understandable. I also would have thought the mobo would keep the port powered only. Useful knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to charge even though the USB is blocked. Most of the time, it is the data ports that are blocked leaving the power ports open for power supply.